# is there any way in 2020 to get stack trace string from a managed package

Tags: apex, managed-package, isv

I have a simple code below in a managed package

```
try {
  //some code here
} catch(Exception ex) {
  log__c log = new log__c();
  log.stackTrace__c = log.getStackTraceString(); 
  log.message_c = log.getMessage();
  insert log;
}
```

But in subscriber org, stack trace string is always null, can someone please confirm if is there anyway to get stacktracestring from managed package and store it in custom object.
     in real time I am using a platform event and trigger on same to capture details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. You'll want to vote on [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000PYqWQAW).

Comment: So there is no way to get at least the class name and method name?

Comment: @gs650x As far as I'm aware, no, you cannot.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your response :(

Comment: It's 2022.  there still isn't.  Maybe in 2032